# Arrangements of "1234123567" such that no two identical numbers are adjacent to each other

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ways to rearrange the sequence “1234123567”, such that no two identical numbers are adjacent to each other (there are two 1’s, two 2’s, and two 3’s). For example, “1123234567” is invalid because the two 1’s are adjacent.

I first tried to use the Inclusion-exclusion principle:

Let $A$ be "there is "11" in the arrangement"
let $B$ be "there is "22" in the arrangement"
let $C$ be "there is "33" in the arrangement"

Then the number of invalid cases should be:

$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$, which means $|A\cup B\cup C|=3\times 9!-3\times (7!\times 2)+6\times 5!=1059120$.

However, when I use the brute-force approach using Python:

```
from itertools import permutations

perm = [''.join(i) for i in permutations("1234123567")]

valid = [n for n in perm if not ("11" in n or "22" in n or "33" in n)]

print(len(valid)) # 1895040
```

it gives $1895040$ as the result.

I wonder why these results don't seem to match? Is any of these results, in fact, true?

Comment: This does not seem to have anything to do with probability or statistics. It could be combinatorics. Anyway, what have you tried? You can **edit** the question to show your efforts.

Comment: In Python, `permutations` does not account for duplicates. I think you could use something like `perm=set(perm)` to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: The total number of ways to rearrange the ten-digit sequence $1234123567$ without any restriction is only ${10\choose2}\cdot{8\choose2}\cdot{6\choose2}\cdot4!=453{,}600$ (i.e., picking two spots for the $1$'s another two spots for the $2$'s, another two spots for the $3$'s and then putting the $4567$ into the remaining four spots), so how can either result be correct?

Comment: You have $|A|=9!$ because you can think of the adjacent 11 as a single symbol, mixed in with the 8 remaining other symbols. This does not take into account the other two pairs of identical symbols, so it should be $9!/(2!2!)$. With $|A\cap B|$, how do you arrive at $7!\cdot2!$ ?

Comment: The right answer is actually 236880 (obtained with the corrected python script)

Answer (score 3):

It is a straight case of inclusion-exclusion

$= \frac{10!}{2!2!2!} - \binom31 \frac{9!}{2!2!}+\binom32\frac{8!}{2!} - \binom33 7! = 236880$

[All arrangements - at least one pair together + at least two pairs together - all three pairs together]

Comment: Well done! It is the correct number of possible combinations and exactly the value which the fixed Python code now produces.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the Python code and now it yields the correct number of combinations as properly derived by *true blue anil*:

```
from itertools import permutations
from collections import OrderedDict

perm = [''.join(i) for i in permutations("1234123567")]

valid = [n for n in perm if not ("11" in n or "22" in n or "33" in n)]
valid = OrderedDict.fromkeys(valid)

print(len(valid)) # 236880
```